# Implicit type conversion does not see a base class match. bug or feature?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

It seems my compiler (GCC 4.7) does not issue an implicit type conversion if the resulting converted type would allow a function call due to a base class match, i.e. conversion result `A` is a `AB`.

```
class AB {};

class A: public AB
{
public:
  A(float i) {}
  A() {}
  A(const A& rhs) {}
  A(A&& rhs) {}
 };

AB operator*(const AB& lhs,const AB& rhs)
{
  // Return default constructed AB
}

void foo() {
  A a;
  auto tmp = 2.0 * a;   // This fails because no conversion rule was found.
}
```

Is this a feature of the C++ language? If so, in what situation would it be better to not match against the base class.

Please, don't answer that the poor compiler has so much to do, and it would be too much to match against base classes.

**EDIT**

```
c.cc:51:20: error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘2.0e+0 * a’
c.cc:51:20: note: candidate is: c.cc:42:1: note: AB operator*(const
AB&, const AB&) c.cc:42:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1
from ‘double’ to ‘const AB&’ c.cc:51:20: error: unable to deduce
‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
```

Comment: Yeah, its just an example to test the conversion facility

Comment: You probably should either rewrite your expression with float: `auto tmp = 2.0f * a;`, or add a constructor for `double` into `A` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please, don't answer that the poor compiler has so much to do, and it would be too much to match against base classes.

No, but what I will tell you is that *the poor compiler has so much to do, and it would be too much to match against all potential derived classes (or other conversions through third types)*

The problem in your code is not the *upcast* from `A` to `AB`, which the compiler gladly does, but the fact that it cannot convert `2.0` to an `AB`. The set of allowed conversions is limited and yields a finite set of work. When you call the operator it finds a match that takes two `AB` objects and it does not know how to directly convert the `double` into `AB`. It is obvious to you that it could create an `A` temporary and then upcast from it, as it upcasted the second argument. It is not so obvious for the compiler that does not know how many potential types derive from `A` (consider other translation units compiled separately) or even unrelated types that can be constructed from a `double` and have conversion operators to `AB`

Comment: You are right. `A` to `AB` is not a conversion. So it's just a 1 part chain of conversion. But on the other hand the standard provides this ill-formed example. A bit confusing

Comment: @juanchopanza: Your answer was not wrong, it was only a nitpick: that is not a second user defined conversion, which does not mean that it is allowed either. And the example you provide is sound. I think the answer has value and should not be deleted.

Comment: `double->float->A->A&->AB&->const AB&`

Comment: Is there a passage that says that base classes do not take part in implicit type conversion checking?

Comment: I don't see the argument with the external compilation unit. You need the header files anyway. And there the conversion rules are specified. So what you are saying is: Its too hard for the compiler.

Comment: @Frank I guess the issue is that the problem isn't constrained enough. What if `AB` had more derived types with implicit conversions from `float`? I cannot think of a sensible way for the compiler to decide which path to choose.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah okay that makes sense. I didn't get that from the comment. Sure, no sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard provides this example of an ill-formed program with a sequence of conversions similar to those in your code. See §13.3.1:

```
class T {
 public:
  T();
};
class C : T {
 public:
  C(int);
};
T a = 1;  // ill-formed: T(C(1)) not tried.
```

Comment: I think there are some zig-zag conversion examples out there that state that more than one user-defined conversion is allowed. Do you have the C++ standard passage for this?

Comment: The conversion `A` to `AB` is **not** a user defined conversion.